# How to fix insert data in android SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm trying to insert the data in the sqlite database but the output is not showing.

activity_main.xml

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:text="Add a new Payment"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextName1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter Invoice id" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter Customer Name" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextName2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter Credit Card" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextName3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter Renewal Date" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextName4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter Expiry Date" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="6dp"
        android:text="Select Packages" />
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerPackages"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/Packages" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextName5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter Total Amount" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonAddPayment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add Payment" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewViewEmployees"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:text="View Payment"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Database Manager class

**Note that: the invoice_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY <--- This is not autoincrement and renewal_date TEXT , expiry_date TEXT, total_amount TEXT <--- Datatype is TEXT**

```
public class DatabaseManager extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Gym.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Payment";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "invoice_id";
public static final String KEY_NAME2 = "customer_name";
public static final String KEY_NAME3 = "credit_card";
public static final String KEY_NAME4 = "renewal_date";
public static final String KEY_NAME5 = "expiry_date";
public static final String KEY_NAME6 = "membership";
public static final String KEY_NAME7 = "total_amount";
public DatabaseManager( Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME +" (invoice_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ,customer_name TEXT ,credit_card TEXT ,renewal_date TEXT , expiry_date TEXT , membership TEXT, total_amount TEXT);");

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}
public boolean insertData(String invoice_id, String customer_name, String credit_card, String renewal_date, String expiry_date, String total_amount, String membership){
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
  contentValues.put(KEY_NAME, invoice_id);
    contentValues.put(KEY_NAME2, customer_name);
    contentValues.put(KEY_NAME3, credit_card);
    contentValues.put(KEY_NAME4, renewal_date);
    contentValues.put(KEY_NAME5, expiry_date);
    contentValues.put(KEY_NAME6, membership);
    contentValues.put(KEY_NAME7, total_amount);
  long result =  db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null, contentValues); // error here
  // If data is inserted incorrectly it will return -1
    if (result == -1) {
      return false;
  }else {
      return true;
  }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   DatabaseManager myDb;
   EditText editInvoiceid, editName, editCreditCard, editRenewDate, 
   editExpiryDate, edittotalamt;
    Spinner membership;
    TextView textViewViewPayments;
   Button btnAddData;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myDb = new DatabaseManager (this);

    //Cast variables over here.
    editInvoiceid = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName1);
    editName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
    editCreditCard = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName2);
    editRenewDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName3);
    editExpiryDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName4);
    edittotalamt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName5);
    textViewViewPayments = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewViewEmployees);
    membership = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerPackages);
    btnAddData = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAddPayment);
    AddData();
}
//Create a method for adding data
public void AddData() {
    btnAddData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
         boolean isInserted = myDb.insertData(editInvoiceid.getText().toString(), editName.getText().toString(),editCreditCard.getText().toString(),editRenewDate.getText().toString(), editExpiryDate.getText().toString(),edittotalamt.getText().toString(), membership.toString());
        if (isInserted == true){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data Inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data Not Inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        }
    });
}
```

}

How to fix this?

Comment: *the output is not showing* means that you see a toast with `"Data Not Inserted"` or does the app crash?

Comment: The best thing for you to do right now is to learn how to use debugger, and step through this activity when it tries to write to SQLite.  Even if a sharpshooter can guess at the problem, you can't keep coming back to Stack Overflow for every minor bug which is bound to creep up in your app.

Comment: Umm I'm not using the emulator I'm using my phone to run the application

Comment: So what is the problem? If your app crashes there is an error log even if you use your phone.

Comment: Nope the app does not crash tho it only says "Data Inserted" but the output is not showing in the database

Comment: How do you know that the data is not inserted? Do you extract the db from the phone?

Comment: Because when ever I'm trying to insert any data... I'm trying to see if the data is saved in the SQLite database but its not saving in the database for some reason.

Comment: *I'm trying to see* how? The database is stored inside a folder in the phone.

Comment: Then how do I see the stored data on the pc?

Comment: You have to extract the db from your phone, or get the rows and show them in an activity.

Comment: I don't know how to extract the db from my phone or get rows. I'm still a novice in Android and Sqlite.

Comment: In this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53935006/im-having-some-issues-in-fetching-data-from-sqlite-database you accepted the answer, this means you managed to fetch data from a db. Just do the same for this db.

Comment: Are you entering non-numerics in the invoiceID? Although you say not AUTOINCREMENT. `invoice_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`  makes the column an alias of **rowid** and therefore the value MUST be an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you have one of two issues.

### Potential Issue 1.

You may have changed the structure of the database and just rerun the App. In which case new columns (as an example) would not exist and this could cause a crash (SQlite Exception).

If you do one of the following before rerunning the App, such an issue would be fixed :-

1. Delete (Clear) the App's data.
2. Uninstall the App.
3. Increase the Database version (*e.g. change `super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);` to `super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 2);`*)

### Potential Issue 2.

Due to the **invoice_id** column being defined as `invoice_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`, the value must be an integer value as INTEGER PRIMARY KEY makes the column an alias of the special column **rowid** which must be an INTEGER value [ROWIDs and the INTEGER PRIMARY KEY](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid) (*AUTOINCREMENT is just an extension that requires the next autoassigned value to be higher than any value that exists or has existed*).

The **invoice_id** also needs to be a unique value.

Saying that, your code works at least to a fashion. The following was used to test you code:-

**activity_main.xml** a minor change to the Spinner was made removing `android:entries="@array/Packages"`.
- This was removed to simplify testing and also because `membership.toString()` will not get the value of the selected item but a string representation of the object (see result below)
**DatabaseManager.java** as per the question (i.e. no changes).
**MainActivity.java** as per :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DBHelper mDBHlpr;

    DatabaseManager myDb;
    EditText editInvoiceid, editName, editCreditCard, editRenewDate, editExpiryDate, edittotalamt;
    Spinner membership;
    TextView textViewViewPayments;
    Button btnAddData;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myDb = new DatabaseManager (this);

        //Cast variables over here.
        editInvoiceid = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName1);
        editName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
        editCreditCard = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName2);
        editRenewDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName3);
        editExpiryDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName4);
        edittotalamt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName5);
        textViewViewPayments = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewViewEmployees);
        membership = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerPackages);
        btnAddData = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAddPayment);
        AddData();
    }
    //Create a method for adding data
    public void AddData() {
        btnAddData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                boolean isInserted = myDb.insertData(editInvoiceid.getText().toString(), editName.getText().toString(),editCreditCard.getText().toString(),editRenewDate.getText().toString(), editExpiryDate.getText().toString(),edittotalamt.getText().toString(), membership.toString());
                if (isInserted == true){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data Inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data Not Inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                logCurrentData(); //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * ADDED METHOD
     */
    private void logCurrentData() {
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(
                myDb.getWritableDatabase().query(DatabaseManager.TABLE_NAME,null,null,null,null,null,null)
        );
    }
}
```

- i.e. method **logCurrentData** has been added and this is invoked in the **onClick** method.

### Results

#### Test 1 Input :-

[image]

Results in (Toasts ***Data Inserted***):-

```
2018-12-31 21:45:40.282 2266-2266/so53976714.so53976714 I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@6a5e922
2018-12-31 21:45:40.282 2266-2266/so53976714.so53976714 I/System.out: 0 {
2018-12-31 21:45:40.282 2266-2266/so53976714.so53976714 I/System.out:    invoice_id=1
2018-12-31 21:45:40.282 2266-2266/so53976714.so53976714 I/System.out:    customer_name=Fred
2018-12-31 21:45:40.282 2266-2266/so53976714.so53976714 I/System.out:    credit_card=1234567890
2018-12-31 21:45:40.282 2266-2266/so53976714.so53976714 I/System.out:    renewal_date=10/19
2018-12-31 21:45:40.282 2266-2266/so53976714.so53976714 I/System.out:    expiry_date=10/19
2018-12-31 21:45:40.282 2266-2266/so53976714.so53976714 I/System.out:    membership=android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner{ec45337 V.ED..CL. ........ 0,320-1080,344 #7f07007c app:id/spinnerPackages}
2018-12-31 21:45:40.282 2266-2266/so53976714.so53976714 I/System.out:    total_amount=50.00
2018-12-31 21:45:40.282 2266-2266/so53976714.so53976714 I/System.out: }
2018-12-31 21:45:40.282 2266-2266/so53976714.so53976714 I/System.out: <<<<<
```

- Note membership is due to memebership.toString() as explained above.

#### Test 2 Change Fred to Bert and try to add :-

results in **Data not inserted** the log includes the following (as well as the exact same data as per the previous test) :-

```
2018-12-31 21:50:14.115 2266-2266/so53976714.so53976714 E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting credit_card=1234567890 renewal_date=10/19 total_amount=50.00 expiry_date=10/19 invoice_id=1 customer_name=Bert membership=android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner{ec45337 V.ED..CL. ........ 0,320-1080,344 #7f07007c app:id/spinnerPackages}
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: Payment.invoice_id (code 1555 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_PRIMARYKEY)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:796)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1564)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1433)
        at so53976714.so53976714.DatabaseManager.insertData(DatabaseManager.java:47)
        at so53976714.so53976714.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:45)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6680)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

- **Note** the exception has been trapped and does not cause a failure.
- As can be seen the value for invoice_id (1 in this case) cannot be duplicated.

#### Test 3 Try changing invoice_id from **1** to **A** (still with Bert instead of Fred):-

Results in **Data not Inserted**. However the log includes :-

```
2018-12-31 21:54:51.818 2266-2266/so53976714.so53976714 E/SQLiteLog: (20) statement aborts at 5: [INSERT INTO Payment(credit_card,renewal_date,total_amount,expiry_date,invoice_id,customer_name,membership) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)] datatype mismatch
2018-12-31 21:54:51.820 2266-2266/so53976714.so53976714 E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting credit_card=1234567890 renewal_date=10/19 total_amount=50.00 expiry_date=10/19 invoice_id=A customer_name=Bert membership=android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner{ec45337 V.ED..CL. ........ 0,320-1080,344 #7f07007c app:id/spinnerPackages}
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatatypeMismatchException: datatype mismatch (code 20 SQLITE_MISMATCH)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:796)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1564)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1433)
        at so53976714.so53976714.DatabaseManager.insertData(DatabaseManager.java:47)
        at so53976714.so53976714.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:45)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6680)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

- again the exception is trapped.

#### Test4 changee the invoice_id to 2 :-

Result **Data Inserted** and the log includes :-

```
2018-12-31 22:10:32.902 2266-2266/so53976714.so53976714 I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@4d18939
2018-12-31 22:10:32.905 2266-2266/so53976714.so53976714 I/System.out: 0 {
2018-12-31 22:10:32.906 2266-2266/so53976714.so53976714 I/System.out:    invoice_id=1
2018-12-31 22:10:32.906 2266-2266/so53976714.so53976714 I/System.out:    customer_name=Fred
2018-12-31 22:10:32.906 2266-2266/so53976714.so53976714 I/System.out:    credit_card=1234567890
2018-12-31 22:10:32.906 2266-2266/so53976714.so53976714 I/System.out:    renewal_date=10/19
2018-12-31 22:10:32.906 2266-2266/so53976714.so53976714 I/System.out:    expiry_date=10/19
2018-12-31 22:10:32.906 2266-2266/so53976714.so53976714 I/System.out:    membership=android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner{ec45337 V.ED..CL. ........ 0,320-1080,344 #7f07007c app:id/spinnerPackages}
2018-12-31 22:10:32.906 2266-2266/so53976714.so53976714 I/System.out:    total_amount=50.00
2018-12-31 22:10:32.906 2266-2266/so53976714.so53976714 I/System.out: }
2018-12-31 22:10:32.906 2266-2266/so53976714.so53976714 I/System.out: 1 {
2018-12-31 22:10:32.906 2266-2266/so53976714.so53976714 I/System.out:    invoice_id=2
2018-12-31 22:10:32.906 2266-2266/so53976714.so53976714 I/System.out:    customer_name=Bert
2018-12-31 22:10:32.906 2266-2266/so53976714.so53976714 I/System.out:    credit_card=1234567890
2018-12-31 22:10:32.906 2266-2266/so53976714.so53976714 I/System.out:    renewal_date=10/19
2018-12-31 22:10:32.906 2266-2266/so53976714.so53976714 I/System.out:    expiry_date=10/19
2018-12-31 22:10:32.906 2266-2266/so53976714.so53976714 I/System.out:    membership=android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner{ec45337 V.ED..CL. ........ 0,320-1080,344 #7f07007c app:id/spinnerPackages}
2018-12-31 22:10:32.906 2266-2266/so53976714.so53976714 I/System.out:    total_amount=50.00
2018-12-31 22:10:32.906 2266-2266/so53976714.so53976714 I/System.out: }
2018-12-31 22:10:32.906 2266-2266/so53976714.so53976714 I/System.out: <<<<<
```